# Bitbucket repo has no branches, can not be cloned

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket, git-clone

I pushed some code to my bitbucket repo and tagged it. Under tags I can see the commits and the code changes, but when I look at the src folder that is empty. There are also no branches and when I try to clone that repo I get

```
warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout
```

I first cloned a skeleton from someone elses repo. Is there a way for me to branch those commits and make it possible for others to clone my repo?

Comment: Why do you need to clone it since you already pushed there?

Comment: Does the command `git push origin master:master` works ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to push to your bitbucket repo:

```
mkdir my-repo
cd my-repo
git init
git remote add origin https://bitbucket.com/path/to/repo.git
touch README.md
git add README.md
git commit -m "Add README.md"
git push --force
```